# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent - Ajax, Node, Express

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, authentication, web-applications

I'm trying to using Airtable, node.js, express.js and jquery to create a simple user authentication functionality but I'm fairly new at this and I'm running into a problem I can't seem to fix and the articles I've read I can't seem to grasp or adapt to my particular situation.

I have this Ajax call in my html doc:

```
$("#checkUser").submit(function(e) {

  var studentID = $('input[name="student"]').val()

  e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
  var form = $(this);
  var url = form.attr('action');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
    success: function(data) {
      $(window).attr("location", window.location.href + 'Dashboard?student=' + studentID);

    },
    error: function(data){
      console.log("User not found. Try again");
    }
  });

});
```

This call sends the inputted username and data to the server which then processes it in the following way:

```
app.post('/checkUser', urlencodedParser, function(request,response){
  var user = JSON.stringify(request.body);
  user = JSON.parse(user);

  base('RegisteredStudents').select({
    filterByFormula: '{UserID} = ' + user.student,
    view: "Grid view"
  }).eachPage(function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
  records.forEach(function(record) {
    response.sendStatus(200);
  });
  fetchNextPage();
  }, function done(error) {
    response.sendStatus(404);
  });
});
```

If the user exists in the database of Airtable, it should send '200' which the Ajax then reacts by redirecting accordingly to the user's profile. Otherwise, if the user does not exist, the server should respond with '404', which the Ajax call should react to by printing a statement in the console. While it does do these two things well, the server breaks down when, after a student puts in the wrong user ID and the Ajax prints the statement, the student tries to put once more a userID. I get the  " Can't set headers after they are sent. " message. Please, how can I solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have two `response.send...`, you can only send data once. Either make sure only one runs with some conditional or add `return` before all `response.send...` so if any of them runs, the program will return and the other `response.send..` will not run.